# Ubuntu 20.04 Server: Cannot Even Ping LUKS-Encrypted Server To Dropbear SSH Unlock It

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, networking, ping, dropbear

i'm running an Ubuntu 20.04 server with LUKS full-disk encryption that i'd like to be able to unlock remotely (LAN and WAN). previously, when the device was locked i was still able to ping the device from a computer on the network; however, since installing dropbear (via [this guide](https://www.cyberciti.biz/security/how-to-unlock-luks-using-dropbear-ssh-keys-remotely-in-linux/)) i am unable to even ping the server from LAN, much less attempt to unlock. could you help me over this hump? n.b.:

- this computer, hostname `cooltown`, has two ethernet ports, and we're
  using `enp9s0`;
- i have run `initramfs-update` after updating my config, yes;
- i am still able to wake-on-LAN this device from my router using the device's MAC address `RE:DA:CT:ED:IT`

results of `ip addr`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp9s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether RE:DA:CT:ED:IT brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.50.69/24 brd 192.168.50.255 scope global dynamic enp9s0
       valid_lft 84962sec preferred_lft 84962sec
    inet6 fe80::426c:8fff:febc:5192/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp10s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether UN:US:ED:IN:TF brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

result of `/etc/dropbear-initramfs/config`

```
#
# Configuration options for the dropbear-initramfs boot scripts.
# You must run update-initramfs(8) to effect changes to this file (like
# for other files under the '/etc/dropbear-initramfs' directory).

#
# Command line options to pass to dropbear(8)
#
DROPBEAR_OPTIONS="-I 180 -j -k -p 2222 -s -c cryptroot-unlock"

#
# On local (non-NFS) mounts, interfaces matching this pattern are
# brought down before exiting the ramdisk to avoid dirty network
# configuration in the normal kernel.
# The special value 'none' keeps all interfaces up and preserves routing
# tables and addresses.
#
#IFDOWN=*
```

result of `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf`

```
#
# initramfs.conf
# Configuration file for mkinitramfs(8). See initramfs.conf(5).
#
# Note that configuration options from this file can be overridden
# by config files in the /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d directory.

# [...]

# Dropbear Stuff
IP=192.168.50.69::192.168.50.255::255.255.255.0:cooltown:enp9s0
```